# Ruby PDF::Reader matching bullet point with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, pdf, pdf-reader

I have parsed a pdf document in Ruby with PDF::Reader. The bullet point of the pdf file appears in my parsed text as a strange cube with F0B7 inside like this (I also attached a print screen):

```
  __
 |F0|
 |B7|
```

I would like to know if I can match this "bullet point" with regex and if so, what would be the appropriate way to do it? I have absolutely no idea to tackle this issue as I am not even sure that this is part of the string in the first place. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a unicode symbol with [codepoint `F0B7`](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=F0B7).

Unfortunately your Ubuntu installation has a default font that misses that glyph, and when glyph is missing in the font definition, the *common approach* is to draw it’s codepoint in a square.

The regexp to match it would be:

```
/\uF0B7/
```

[image]